# Change image with page width resize

Tags: javascript, html, image, resize, width

I need some help with this JavaScript code, I'm all new to using javascript so when I get stuck it gets annoying. 
What I'm trying to do is change the image displayed on my nav bar when on small screens (mobiles) because the nav bar color changes. What I have come up with so far by searching online and some playing only works when the screen size is manually reduced and then the image changes like it should. However I want it to load in this state as well and thats where I am stuck.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
  var win = $(this);
  if (win.width() < 768) { 
      $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logowhite.png');
  } else {
    $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logodark.png');
}});
```

Could this be done in the css instead is also a question I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo in fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/User86745458/99nfoge9/)

JS

```
function resize(){
    if ($(window).width() < 768) { 
      $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/chrome_ntp_white_logo2.png');
  } else {
    $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
  }
}
resize();
$(window).on('resize', resize);
```

HTML

```
<div class='navbar-brand'>
    <img src=''/>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same issue with this, It works perfectly if I reduce the window size by dragging it. But when the browser loads already reduced it doesn't show the change until there is a movement in the window width

Comment: Very quickly I also have code that changes the icon when scrolling, I only use this when on large displays. Is their any way to only let this script work when over by 768 width. `$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logowhite.png'); 
    } else {
        $(".navbar-brand img").attr('src', 'img/icons/logodark.png');      
    }
});`

Answer (score 1):

> Could this be done in the css instead is also a question I have?

It is far easier and better in CSS than in Javascript!

Read this question:
[Responsive design with media query : screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574881/responsive-design-with-media-query-screen-size)

**Code to change background image with CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    div {
        background-image: url("img/icons/logowhite.png");
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) {
    div {
        background-image: url("img/icons/logodark.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had a read. I'm using the media query to change all the nav bar background color and link colors. But I don't know how to change a img to a different img using this to be able to achieve what I'm looking for. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about mobile devices.  Are you maybe trying this code in a mobile or a simulator?? You said the code works when resizing the screen manually. If you refer to the resize event on mobiles, maybe it will not work if you dont look at the orientation change event.

Check if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9824480/3617531) helps you

Comment: I was simply resizing the browser by dragging it to see if it was working then I would try on my iphone to make sure it came out how I wanted to on a mobile

Comment: if it´s for a mobile, i strongly recomend you to search by the orientation. 

There are also media queries that will make your life easier! 

Check this for example!! 
http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change