# In django-tables2, make number of rows displayed depend on screen size?

Tags: django, django-tables2

When using django-tables2, use the `paginate` parameter to limit the number of rows displayed. For instance, if I have the table `my_table`, then in `views.py` I set it to display 10 rows as follows:

```
RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page':10}).configure(my_table)
```

My problem is that in my app I want the number of rows shown per page to depend on how big the user's screen is. For instance, 10 rows for mobile devices, but 25 rows for desktop screens. I am imagining doing in `views.py` what you can do with style sheets using the media rule (e.g., `@media(max-height: 480px) {do something}`).

Unfortunately, my (noob) understanding is that in Django, the view is relatively insulated from low-level parameters like screen size. However, I don't want to implement some scheme like sending information from the template to the view if there is already a simple solution baked into django-tables2 that I am just ignorant of.

Note I am using Bootstrap4 for my front end, if that makes any difference. The point is that I am already importing Javascript and jQuery into the project, at least at the template level.

**Related general discussion**
Interestingly, I haven't seen a lot of discussion of adapting table row count to media type, but there is obviously tons of more general discussion of responsive media-sensitive design:

- [Responsive design with media query : screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574881/responsive-design-with-media-query-screen-size)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 1):

I have no straightforward or complete solution, but I'll share some thoughts:

When (initially) rendering the table, Django-tables2 has no way of knowing the screen size. One of these workarounds might satisfy your needs:

**Render less rows**

In your initial page view, if your screen size is small:

- Hide some rows, then, adjust the offset and number of pages you request for the next pages using JavaScript. This will involve rewriting url parameters of the pagination links.
- Reload the page with a smaller number for `per_page` added to the url.
- Default to rendering a smaller number of rows, and allow the user to change the number of rows rendered with a dropdown, which is hidden for mobile users.

**Optimize template for responsiveness**

Optimize the template for different screen sizes rather than changing the number of rows. An example of how this could work can be found in the table displayed in [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). You might still want less rows for smaller screens with this technique though.

**Client-side table-sorting**

If the total number of rows is reasonable, sending everything to the client and deferring the pagination to something like [datatables](https://datatables.net/) might work.

Comment: Thanks Jieter.  I have considered datatables, but I *really* like django-tables2, which at this point is embedded deeply into my project so I really don't want to mess with it. I have thought a lot about this, and with my project basically done it is clear the best solution is to have variable row numbers, with second best being a small fixed number of rows that is optimized for phones, and less optimal for big screens (right now I show ten rows).

Comment: Changing the number of rows seems more complicated than I appreciated. The problem is Django purposely doesn't care about screens and the front end stuff. That's sort of the whole point I guess. I wonder what the most clever way to get `@media` information to the view would be? Sneak it in as a GET request from the base template to the view?

Comment: It's not that django doesn't care, but rather that it's fundamentally designed for a different internet than we have today. Even now, some people prefer to see the same interface across all devices and don't like responsive interfaces...

Comment: After reflection on your first idea: I'd start with 10 rows (or whatever small number works), and have a dropdown menu only for people on larger screens. I don't *like* it, because we would end up changing my `urls.py` file for every view with a table, just to add a 'number_rows' argument, and it starts to feel inelegant. But that was your point: if you really want to do this from the server-side, it is impossible to keep this kind of control elegant. It makes me a bit sad. :(

Comment: You don't need to have the `number_rows` parameter part of the url, you can just as well use a query param: `/tableview/3/?per_page=25` and use `request.GET.get('per_page', 10)` to default to 10.

Comment: @neuronet If you think my answer resolves your question, can you accept it?